Why does locate.outliers() detect more outliers than tso() in the tsoutliers package?
I am working with the tsoutliers package in R for outlier detection in time series data. Both functions, locate.outliers() and tso(), are used for detecting outliers, but I am observing different results (means table of detected outliers) between the two functions, even though the inputs appear to be the same.
Here is the code I used:
# Using locate.outliers()
m_opt <- Arima(x, order = c(8, 1, 0),
               seasonal = list(order = c(1, 1, 1), period = 7),
               xreg = fourier(x, K = 3)) 
resid <- residuals(m_opt) # residuals
pars <- coefs2poly(m_opt) # collapses the polynomials of an ARIMA model
outliers <- locate.outliers(resid, pars, types = c("TC", "AO", "LS"), cval = 3.77)
print(outliers) # result

# Using tso()
tso_opt <- tso(x, types = c("TC", "AO", "LS"), xreg = fourier(x, K = 3), 
               tsmethod = "arima", 
               args.tsmethod = list(order = c(8, 1, 0),
                                    seasonal = list(order = c(1, 1, 1), period = 7)), 
               cval = 3.77)
print(tso_opt$outliers) # result

The results from locate.outliers() include more detected outliers compared to tso().
I would like to understand:

Why does locate.outliers() detect more outliers than tso() in this
scenario?
Are there any internal differences in how these two
functions handle residuals, critical values (cval), or outlier
types? I've checked and the resulting ARIMA model and cval is the same in the output.
What adjustments (if any) should I make to align the outputs
of the two functions?


Have you looked at the docs? "‘tso0’ is mostly a wrapper function around the functions ‘locate.outliers’ and ‘discard.outliers’. ‘tso’ iterates around ‘tso0’ first for the original series and then for the adjusted series. The process stops if no additional outliers are found in the current iteration or if ‘maxit’
iterations are reached." ...

Also, hard to say without a reproducible example: can you dput(x) and show us the results?

@BenBolker Thank you for your response. I checked the GitHub repository but couldn't find the loop for locate.outliers() within the tso() function. The documentation states: "Then, the time series model is fitted (or selected) again for the adjusted series, and a new search for outliers is executed. The outer loop stops when no additional outliers are detected." Based on this, I’d expect it to iteratively add outliers. However, it seems after each iteration, the effects of detected outliers are recalculated, and some may actually be removed.
